# Getting specific child from Firebase for Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Let say I have this JSON file inside the Realtime Database:

[image]

And i try to print both humidity and temperature value into my `EditText` and I was using this code :

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://xxx-xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx.xxxxxx-xxxxxx.firebasedatabase.app/")
reference = database.getReference("data")

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent( object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange (dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (data in dataSnapshot.children) {
                        temp.setText(data.child("temp").value.toString())
                        hum.setText(data.child("hum").value.toString())
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })
    }
```

As the result inside the Temp and Hum `EditText` it's getting `null` values. And so I tried to print something to see am I doing right, I did `print(data.value.toString())` and only return `temp` value with missing `hum` value.

Comment: Try setting the reference to `reference = database.getReference("data").child(temp)`.

Comment: @Dharmaraj and how about the `hum` value? am i need to specify them one by one?

Comment: Can you clarify which node are you trying to read? I thought you only wanted to read the value of temp and not hum

Comment: you can recheck my question again, i want to print both things. @Dharmaraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to get the values of the `hum` property and `temp` property, there is no need for any loop. So simply use the following lines of code:

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://xxx-xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx.xxxxxx-xxxxxx.firebasedatabase.app/")
reference = database.getReference("data")

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent( object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange (dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            temp.setText(dataSnapshot.child("temp").getValue(String::class.java))
            hum.setText(dataSnapshot.child("hum").getValue(String::class.java))
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
})
```

This code will set the value of `66.00` to the `temp` EditText and the value of `28.00` to the `hum` EditText.